# Boot from USB with second USB disk present

Tags: usb, boot

I am booting a RPI3 B Plus via USB from an mSATA drive (using the Desktop Pi enclosure). This works fine. My kernel command-line uses the partition UUID to identify the root partition:

```
root=PARTUUID=xxx
```

When, at boot time, an additional USB stick is present (which is DOS-formatted and entirely empty)

- if the second device is plugged in right below the boot disk (boot disk top-right USB port, if looked at from the outside, and second disk bottom-right), the device boots.
- if the second device is plugged in on the left side (either top or bottom slot), the device does not boot. In this case, the green LED never even flashes once.

Why is that? Is it possible that the left USB ports are being consulted by the boot loader before the right ones, and the bootloader doesn't bother to look further if it already found a device even if it is not bootable? Because if I copy `/boot/*` to the root of the second USB device, it does boot again, even if plugged in on the left side.

If so, I'd consider that a bug. Or what am I getting wrong / should be doing differently?

Comment: run `sudo blkid` - does `/dev/sda1` have the same PARTUUID as `/dev/sda2` for example? If so, perhaps the boot process sees the PARTUUID "prefix" is correct on the first disk it sees (the USB disk) and figures the it has the right disk (makes sense to me) - do `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` (i.e. the whole disk) have the same `PTUUID`? (run `sudo blkid /dev/sda /dev/sdb` to see this if it's not shown in the above command)

Comment: Good thought, but no: all uuids are different.

Comment: what about PARTUUID's?

Comment: I meant all kinds of UUIDs, including PARTUUIDs.

Comment: fair enough - does seem like a bug, doesn't it - or it could be designed that way - the first stage bootloader (which is stored in ROM on the SoC) is limited in size, perhaps it only tried to boot from the first USB drive it finds?

Comment: correction, just read the boot flow and it seems that the pi should enumerate all USB mass storage devices, and look in each until bootcode.bin is found - so it's a mystery

Comment: @JaromandaX Do you have a pointer to the source code in question? Your reading of the code seems to conflict with Ingo's comment below.

Comment: Source code? I'm referring to the boot loader on rom

Comment: read [this doc](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/bootflow.md) - note this first starts talking about `program_gpio_bootmode` which is like `program_usb_boot_mode` but allows you to control boot devices to a degree with GPIO pins - ignore this part, the boot rom boot flow is described (again ignore the references to GPIO pins) at the sentence `Next the boot ROM checks each of the boot sources for a file called bootcode.bin;` - here it clearly states that USB MD (mass storage) devices are enumerated and searched in sequence for `bootcode.bin`

Comment: I just noticed that the behavior appears to be different based on the fdisk partition type of the second (non-boot) disk. If it is "Linux", the root disk is not found. If it is "b" (W95 FAT32), it works. I have not exhaustively tested this, but that's the current observation.

Comment: I think the boot (not root) partition must be a FAT partition, and the root should be a linux partition

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special about the FAT partition which contains the boot files, and the-loader is very basic. At that stage PARTUUID is irrelevant. AFAIK the first enumerated device is used.

You could use a SD Card with just the boot partition.

Comment: Hmm, but why would the bootloader stop at the first encountered device that doesn't even have any files on it?

Comment: try even an SD card with just `bootcode.bin` on a FAT partition - see if that makes any difference

Comment: @JohannesErnst Seems the bootloader has a fix build in sequence to look for an attached device and tries to boot from it. That's it. It will not scan all possible boot devices.

Comment: @ingo Do you have a pointer to the source code in question? Your reading of the code seems to conflict with JaromadaX's comment above.

Comment: @JohannesErnst I don't know much about the boot code but the code in question is embedded in the boot ROM and afaik not open source. Look at [Boot flow](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/bootflow.md) how it works. There is no conflict: *@Jaromanda X* talks about a slot containing boot code and btw. the SD Card is always the first slot tested. If it contains a SD Card without `bootcode.bin` the RasPi will stuck. I'm talking about slots not containing boot code.

Comment: @JohannesErnst I'm talking about slots containing storage not containing boot code.